# What would be the SQLite query for filtering from local database?

Tags: ios, json, sqlite, extract

In my local DB, one column keeps total json data, I want to use query and my filtering parameter is one of the key of json.

I saw some post we can use "json_extract" but I am not sure why it is not working....

My query is this

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ( Type='States' )
AND  json_extract(Data, '$.CountryId=1053')
```

For your better understanding I am providing screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `json_extract` function will only extract data for you. You need to do the comparison *after* you have extracted the field. Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table  WHERE ( Type='States' ) AND  json_extract(Data, '$.CountryId') = 1053
```

or, depending on the type of `CountryId` this might work better:

```
SELECT * FROM table  WHERE ( Type='States' ) AND  json_extract(Data, '$.CountryId') = '1053'
```